# how to conditionally average across columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out the best way to create a new column which is the average of some columns based on the values of other columns. The new column would be the average of columns A and B as long as at least one A_flag or B_flag is true.

```
cols = ['A','A_flag','B','B_flag']
d= [(5,False,3,False),(2,False,7,True),(1,True,10,True),(12,True,2,False)]
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=cols,data=d)
df
    A   A_flag  B   B_flag
0   5   False   3   False
1   2   False   7   True
2   1   True    10  True
3   12  True    2   False
```

For this example, the first row would produce a value of Nan since both flags are false.  The others would be the average -> 4, 4.5, 5.5, 7.

I know I could create an additional column using something like the following and then aggregate the result, but I guess there is something much more efficient.   `df['A_flag'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x is True else 1)`

Comment: `df[['A','B']].mean(1).where(df[['A_flag','B_flag']].any(1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `np.where` and `any`

```
df['new'] = np.where(df[['A_flag','B_flag']].any(1), df[['A','B']].mean(1), np.nan)
df
Out[113]: 
    A  A_flag   B  B_flag  new
0   5   False   3   False  NaN
1   2   False   7    True  4.5
2   1    True  10    True  5.5
3  12    True   2   False  7.0
```